# How to check the signal handler in Linux

Tags: c, linux, shell, linux-kernel

I have read this discussion which discuss about how to check the signal actions of each process:
[How can I check what signals a process is listening to?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85364/how-can-i-check-what-signals-a-process-is-listening-to)

However, I want to use C/C++, Python or other ways to get the userspace of the signal handler name of each process. Just like the psig in Solaris:
[What is the meaning of every column when executing psig command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163573/what-is-the-meaning-of-every-column-when-executing-psig-command)

Would it be possible to do that in Linux?

Comment: The Linux kernel does not expose this info _for processes other than your own_ over syscalls. `/proc/<pid>/status` is your only interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the Linux kernel does not expose the signal handlers (other than using the  `sigaction()` (or `signal()`) syscall in the process itself), you need to inject executable code to the target process to obtain this information.

(Or, alternatively, create a Linux kernel module that exposes this information.)

So, this is definitely a [c](/questions/tagged/c) [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) question.

Note that it is not possible to always obtain the *name* of a function, because the handler can be declared `static void` without any particular name in the binary.

---

The easiest approach would be to create a dynamic library to interpose `signal()` and `sigaction()`, with an ELF constructor function (not related to C++; Linux ELF binaries just support marking functions "constructor", in which case they are automatically executed prior to `main()`) that opens a suitable log file in write-only append mode, say `/var/log/sighandlers/PID.log`, and dumps the contents of `/proc/self/maps` to record the addresses the binaries are loaded in.  The interposed functions will then simply write the addresses of newly assigned handlers to the log file.

It is important to note that both `sigaction()` and `signal()` are [async-signal safe functions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html), so the interposed versions should be, too. (Fortunately, you only need `write()`, which is async-signal safe. I recommend using `dlsym()` to look up the original function pointers in the ELF constructor function.)

When examining the log file, the function addresses should be calculated relative to the beginning of the binary mapping, then `objdump -tT binary` or `objdump -d binary` to find the symbol the address belongs to.

I would personally not bother with any other approaches, even if this requires one to execute each binary using a special command (setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) to find them out; it is either that, or a kernel module.